# Optimizar hilos en Python

Tags: python, hilos

He creado una funcion que hace un ping a las IP que le pase por parametro

Por ejemplo:

```
funcPing (10, [0, 256], 10 , 10) #tarda 10 seg en ser ejecutada y hace ping a todas las ips de tipo 10.X.10.10

funcPing (192, 168, [0, 10], [0, 256]) #tarda 60 segundos  en ser ejecutada y hace ping a todas las ips tipo 192.168.0-10.X
```

Decir que el tiempo no viene determinado por una funcion time si no que depende de la cantidad de operaciones que realiza internamente y que puedo separar la llamada a la funcion de la siguiente manera.

funcPing (192, 168, [0, 10], [0, 256]) puede ser fragmentada en

- funcPing (192, 168, [0, 6], [0, 256]) tarda 30 seg
- funcPing (192, 168, [6, 10],
  [0, 256]) tarda 30 seg

Cual seria la mejor manera de paralelizar el codigo de tal modo que tarde lo menos posible sin tener que estar calculando cuantos hilos necesita cada tarea

Lo he intentado de las 2 siguientes maneras pero en ambos casos, he tenido que calcular a mano cuantos hilos necesita. Ademas, me gustaria saber si es posible hacer que cuando finalice un hilo, este se ponga a ejecutar las operaciones que los otros hilos aun no han podido ejecutar

```
with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    executor.submit(ping, 10, [0, 256], 10 , 10)
    executor.submit(ping, 192, 168, [0, 6], [0, 256])
    executor.submit(ping, 192, 168, [6, 10], [0, 256])
```

Y tambien

```
t1 = threading.Thread(target=ping,args=(10, [0, 256], 10 , 10)
t2 = threading.Thread(target=ping,args=(192, 168, [0, 6], [0, 256])
t3 = threading.Thread(target=ping,args=(192, 168, [6, 10], [0, 256])

t1.start()
t2.start()
t3.start()

t1.join()
t2.join()
t3.join()
```

¿Existe alguna funcionalidad donde yo espeficique el numero de hilos a utilizar y las llamadas a funciones y esta las optimice?

Comment: Usar un patrón productor-consumidor con concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor como haces creo que es lo más simple  (y por cierto esto ya automáticamente hace que un hilo coja alguna tarea disponible cuando  termina la que estaba procesando). ¿La función es tuya? Lo digo porque posiblemente que una llamada a la función haga ping a una sola dirección pudiera ser lo óptimo si quieres usar hilos.

Comment: Piensa un poco: ¿en qué parte del código tienes un problema que se pueda solucionar con más hilos de ejecución? Supongamos que todos los *pings* se hacen eternos. Nada vas a mejorar por más que añadas hilos. Además, si limitas el número máximo de hilos, habrá hilos que nuncan tendrán la oportunidad de ejecutarse. En la práctica, se consigue más optimización usando un único hilo que lance [*asíncronamente*](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/asyncio-task.html) todos los *pings* y espere las secuencia de respuestas.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo mejor es crear un set de todas las IPs a las que quieres hacer ping. Si te pasan `192, 168, 1, [0, 2]`, pues haces un set de 4-tuplas: `( (192, 168, 1, 0), (192, 168, 1, 1) )`.

Luego crea la cantidad de hilos que quieras y con un bucle vas cogiendo una IP cada vez y la envías al hilo que esté sin hacer nada. El hilo principal se encarga de repartir las IPs. Cada vez que un hilo termine, le mandas otra IP hasta que no quede nada.

Al tenerlo así organizado no tienes que pensar en ver cuánto trabajo tiene cada hilo en cada momento. Aunque comiencen siendo 15 IPs para cada hilo, nunca vas a saber si uno de los hilos terminará sus 15 mientras los otros llevan 1 o 2 (es poco probable, pero posible, y no hay forma de saberlo de antemano). Así cada hilo tendrá un trabajo siempre hasta que no queden.